# cat file reader with line numbering

Tags: code-golf

You must do a program that reads a file given in first argument and print it's content to STDOUT and number the lines on the file, the numbers should be followed by a space.
For instance, assuming that your program is named cat, we could write
`./cat "myfile.txt"` (or execute it with its interpreter)

With myfile.txt:

```
Hello, world, this
is a file with
multiple characters..0
```

And the program should output to STDOUT :

```
1  Hello, world, this
2  is a file with
3  multiple characters..0
```

The shortest program in bytes win.

For example :

Perl

```
$r++&print"$r ".$_ while<>
```

Comment: Well, this one is a bit simpler than the Line numbering - implement nl. On this last one, there are restrictions on the length of the file and the program must return error codes. What I want to do here is the smallest program in many languages for just a simple thinks, no matter the length of the file and with only one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

## LabVIEW, 32 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

Reads line by line and concatenates numbers space and newlines, then deletes a trailing number, space and newline.

[image]